# Apache2 MPM event: More threads vs more processes?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, fastcgi

We're running an **Apache2** web server with **MPM event** and **PHP-FPM**. To serve high traffic with minimal server resources I did some research about how to configure MPM best.

Let's say we want to serve a maximum of **512** concurrent connections. So we gonna set [MaxRequestWorkers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) to **512**. With otherwise Apache2 defaults, this alone won't work, since default [ThreadsPerChild](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mpm_common.html#threadsperchild) (**25**) in combination with default [ServerLimit](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mpm_common.html#serverlimit) (**16**) only allows a maximum of **25** x **16** = **400** concurrent connections.

We have now two possibilities:

1. Raise the **ThreadsPerChild** directive (in case together with [ThreadLimit](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mpm_common.html#threadlimit)) to allow more threads per Apache2 child process.
2. Raise **ServerLimit** to allow more child processes to be spawned.

But of course we could also set **ThreadsPerChild** and **ThreadLimit** both to **512** and **ServerLimit** to **1**, don't we?

Doing some research about a reasonable balance, I found these two topics:

- https://serverfault.com/a/146382/577419
- https://www.woktron.com/secure/knowledgebase/133/How-to-optimize-Apache-performance.html

In both it is pointed out that threads consume less static memory, due to shared libraries and cache data shared across all threads of a process, and less CPU cycles to start and stop. The question on ServerFault discusses the downside when running more threads in less processes, since all threads die when the process dies for some reason. So having more processes would increase reliability of the web server. The PHP **memory_limit** AFAIK does not play a role here in case of PHP-FPM, does it?

<s>I remember reading somewhere that each Apache2 child process is only able to perform one PHP-FPM request at a time, but I cannot find that statement anymore. That of course would be a reason to align the amount of Apache2 processes with the amount of PHP-FPM children. But is this true? I'm not sure how it can be tested since even in case of all PHP-FPM children being in use, the next free one is assigned automatically.</s> **(see EDIT below)**

Since I never faced a dying Apache2 child process, I would indeed go with a single one and as much threads as system memory allows. Aside of the reliability aspect, does anyone know other downsides of this strategy? I can only guess there is a reason why **16** is the default, but I couldn't find a satisfying explanation.

---

**EDIT: With a single Apache2 MPM event child and a static amount of 12 PHP-FPM listeners, I enabled the PHP-FPM status page and after one night:**

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      static
start time:           23/Dec/2020:00:39:06 +0100
start since:          53736
accepted conn:        42942
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     0
idle processes:       11
active processes:     1
total processes:      12
max active processes: 12
max children reached: 0
slow requests:        0
```

- **max active processes: 12** can be taken as a prove that a single Apache2 process can utilise multiple PHP-FPM processes, I guess?
- **max children reached: 0** is probably always the case when using **process manager: static**?
- Since **total processes** == **max active processes** in this static case, I should increase the amount of children to speed up web server responses during peak time? Although **max listen queue: 0** means that there was no delayed request yet? A bid too much of an coincidence that all 12 listeners were active already but not a single request more that needed to be queued? I'll continue watching the values and doing some research.
  **EDIT: That `max listen queue` shows always `0` is a known limitation on Linux: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80739**